Cannot resolve type "http://schemas.syncfusion.com/maui:core:SfChip"
I am migrating my app to the new .NET MAUI (with .NET 8). I am using syncfusion as my component library and now when i build my app i get the error 
"Cannot resolve type "http://schemas.syncfusion.com/maui:core:SfChip"".
I already tried deleting the bin and obj folders but that didnt help.
I also found this stackoverflow with kinda the same problem. The answer here states to add a x:Name, but i already have added this but with x:Name="Self".

Your issue has nothing to do with the mentioned link, you are probably using the wrong namespace for the chip control try this:
xmlns:chip="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Core"

And then try using it
<chip:SfChipGroup DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <chip:SfChipGroup.ChipLayout>
        <FlexLayout 
            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
        /> 
    </chip:SfChipGroup.ChipLayout>
</chip:SfChipGroup> 


Ah you are right. I let my imports be done automatticly and it put the import like
xmlns:core="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/maui"
I just assumed this was correct since the IDE suggested this to me. Thanks for the help!
